# gerund form of a word in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, porter-stemmer

I'd like to get the gerund form of a string. I have not found a straightforward way to invoke a library to get the gerund.

I applied the rules for words ending in 'ing`, but because I am getting some errors due to exceptions. Then, I am checking against the cmu words to ensure the generated gerund word is correct. The code looks as follows:

```
import cmudict
import re

ing= 'ing'
vowels = "aeiou"
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
words=['lead','take','hit','begin','stop','refer','visit']
cmu_words= cmudict.words()
g_w = []

for word in words:
    if word[-1] == 'e':
        if word[:-1] + ing in cmu_words:
            g_w.append(word[:-1] + ing)             
    elif count_syllables(word) == 1 and word[-2] in vowels and word[-1] in consonants:
        if word.__len__()>2 and word[-3] in vowels:
            if word + ing in cmu_words:
                g_w.append(word + ing)                 
        else:
            if word + word[-1] + ing in cmu_words:
                g_w.append(word + word[-1] + ing)
    elif count_syllables(word)>1 and word[-2] in vowels and word[-1] in consonants:
        if word + word[-1]+ ing in cmu_words:
            g_w.append(word + word[-1]+ ing)            
        else:
            if word + ing in cmu_words:
                g_w.append(word + ing) 
    
print(g_w)
```

The rules are as follow:

```
when a verb ends in "e", drop the "e" and add "-ing". For example: "take + ing = taking".
when a one-syllable verb ends in vowel + consonant, double the final consonant and add "-ing". For example: "hit + ing = hitting".
When a verb ends in vowel + consonant with stress on the final syllable, double the consonant and add "-ing". For example: "begin + ing = beginning".
Do not double the consonant of words with more than one syllable if the stress is not on the final
```

Is there a more efficient way to get the gerunds of a string if exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. [Library](https://pypi.org/project/pyinflect/) called `pyinflect`

> A python module for word inflections that works as a spaCy extension. To use standalone, import the method getAllInflections and/or getInflection and call them directly. The method getInflection takes a lemma and a Penn Treebank tag and returns a tuple of the specific inflection(s) associated with it.

There is a variety of tags available for getting inflections including the 'VBG' tag (Verb, Gerund) you are looking for.

```
pos_type = 'A'
* JJ      Adjective
* JJR     Adjective, comparative
* JJS     Adjective, superlative
* RB      Adverb
* RBR     Adverb, comparative
* RBS     Adverb, superlative

pos_type = 'N'
* NN      Noun, singular or mass
* NNS     Noun, plural

pos_type = 'V'
* VB      Verb, base form
* VBD     Verb, past tense
* VBG     Verb, gerund or present participle
* VBN     Verb, past participle
* VBP     Verb, non-3rd person singular present
* VBZ     Verb, 3rd person singular present
* MD      Modal
```

Here is a sample implementation.

```
#!pip install pyinflect
from pyinflect import getInflection

words = ['lead','take','hit','begin','stop','refer','visit']
[getInflection(i, 'VBG') for i in words]
```

```
[('leading',),
 ('taking',),
 ('hitting',),
 ('beginning',),
 ('stopping', 'stoping'),
 ('referring',),
 ('visiting',)]
```

**NOTE:** The authors have setup a more sophisticated and benchmarked library which does both lemmatization and inflections called `LemmInflect`. Do check [this](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect) out if you want something more reliable than the above library. The syntax is pretty much the same as above.