# Getting the adjectives and plurals of lemma's in various languages

Tags: python, nlp, lemmatization, inflector

Could anyone point me to a solution/lib to instead of lemmatise, to do inflection(?). And for multiple languages (English, Dutch, German and French).

Or to give an example. I have the lemma 'science' for which I need the words 'sciences', 'scientific', 'scientifically'... returned. So plural and adjectives.

I looked into NLTK (cf Wordnet and Spacy), but did not find a solution.

Comment: I think the plural of "lemma" is "lemmata"

Comment: If you have a function `lemmatise` and a long list of all words in your language (for instance, the official Scrabble dictionary) then you can group the words by lemma in a python dict: `groups = {}; for word in list_of_words: groups.setdefault(lemmatise(word), []).append(word)` and now all words that have lemma `'science'` will be grouped in `groups['science']`.

Comment: Similar questions: [gerund form of a word in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977817/gerund-form-of-a-word-in-python); [How to get inflections for a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653815/how-to-get-inflections-for-a-word-using-wordnet)

Comment: Checkout: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lemmatization-approaches-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can invert a `lemmatise` function by applying it to every word in the [Scrabble dictionary](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/38366/latest-collins-scrabble-words-list-in-text-file/38386#38386), and grouping words with a common stem in a python dict.

Of course the groups will strongly depend on the `lemmatise` function you have. Below, I use `nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize`, which correctly groups `'science'` and `'sciences'` under the same stem `'science'`, but doesn't group `'scientific'` with them.

So you'll need a more "brutal" lemmatise function that brings more words to the same stem.

```py
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
d = {}
with open('scrabble_dict.txt', 'r') as f:
    next(f); next(f) # skip header
    for word in f:
        word = word.strip().lower()
        d.setdefault(wnl.lemmatize(word), []).append(word)

print(d['science'])
# ['science', 'sciences']

print(d['scientific'])
# ['scientific']

print([stem for stem in d if stem.startswith('scien')])
# ['science', 'scienced', 'scient', 'scienter', 'sciential', 'scientific', 'scientifical', 'scientifically', 'scientificities', 'scientificity', 'scientise', 'scientised', 'scientises', 'scientising', 'scientism', 'scientisms', 'scientist', 'scientistic', 'scientize', 'scientized', 'scientizes', 'scientizing']

print(d['lemma'])
# ['lemma', 'lemmas', 'lemmata']
```